# Apache Sling and scriptlets

Tags: jsp, sling

I'm new to Apache Sling and I see in all the examples that it uses JSP scriptlets to render the pages.

Seriously? Is there a way to use normal java code instead of a technique considered obsolete, and discouraged by Sun itself more than 10 years ago due to all the disadvantages it presents?

Or maybe there is an obscure reason where the use of scriptlets is the best choice for the implementation and I'm not aware of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't like scriptlets you can also use taglibs and EL. For a quick overview, see [the latest version of the TLD file](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/sling/trunk/bundles/scripting/jsp-taglib/src/main/resources/META-INF/sling.tld?view=markup) in the Sling SVN repository. You can of course use Javascript, Groovy, Ruby or any other scripting language supported by Sling.

As for the taglibs, to quote [SLING-2648: Add Resource Access Tags](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SLING-2648) , you can use them to do things like

```
<c:set var="currentResource" value="${sling:getResource(resourceResolver,'/etc')}" />
<c:forEach var="child" items="${sling:listChildResources(currentResource)}">
    <c:if test="${child.name != 'jcr:content'}">
        <sling:getResource var="pageContent" path="${child.path}/jcr:content" />
        <sling:adapt adaptable="${pageContent}" adaptTo="org.apache.sling.api.resource.ValueMap" var="childProperties" />
        <sling:getProperty key="jcr:title" defaultValue="${child.name}" var="title" properties="${childProperties}" />
        <li><a href="${child.path}.html">Title: ${title}</a></li>
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: The latest version of the TLD has been renamed to sling.tld.  Here are links to [version 1.3](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/sling/trunk/bundles/scripting/jsp-taglib/src/main/resources/META-INF/sling.tld?revision=1494174&view=markup) (as of rename) and [HEAD](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/sling/trunk/bundles/scripting/jsp-taglib/src/main/resources/META-INF/sling.tld?view=markup) (now set to 1.4).

Answer (score 1):

Sling leaves a lot of freedom as to how you process requests and render pages. You could use Java code only, via OSGi services and request processing servlets, server-side scripting only using a variety of languages and templating systems, full client-side rendering using Sling's default JSON rendering, or any combination of these techniques.

There are probably a number of "suboptimal" examples floating around but you can very much select the request processing and rendering method that suits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Good Sling Devs don't use JSP anymore. It's just in the documentation and examples because it was the standard for so long.

The JSPs, which you rightly see as a crime (or anti pattern), contain two things:

- presentation
- business logic

These need to be separated into different files.

**For Presentation**

Use "Sightly," which is now called "HTL." Read up on these:

- https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/htl/docs/getting-started.htm
- https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/scripting/scripting-htl.html

Sightly is a modern server-side presentation framework, which *properly* separates business logic from presentation declaration, the same way as any other framework you're familiar with, such as Handlebars or FreeMarker, or even facelets.

True, it's not a syntax used outside of the Sling framework, so it's not re-usable knowledge, but you really can learn it entirely in about an hour, and it is elegant and slick.

You can use any other presentation logic you wish, including

- handlebars
- Groovy GSP
- FreeMarker
- ThymeLeaf

BUT - none of these will work "out of the box." You'll have to find the proper "script engines" and install them yourself, or write a scriptengine yourself which enables these in Sling. For example, the popular Adobe AEM product, which *is* Sling, ships with a handlebars scriptengine out of the box. If you're willing to do that work, every presentation framework under the sun is available to you.

**For Business Logic**

If you went with Sightly (aka HTL) for presentation, you'll use the "use" api to declare what script or Class prepares your business logic for that presentation. Here you have practically only 2 options "out of the box":

- JavaScript (Note: Server Side!)
- Java

The goal is for one of these languages to provide a "backing bean" type business logic that gets data for you and prepares it to be rendered by your presentation. In order for your sightly presentation to declare which "bean" or script it uses, you use the "use API" here:

https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/htl/docs/use-api.html

Example:

```
<div data-sly-use.bean="myscript.js">${bean.valueFromJavascript}</div>
```

Now, you can use MANY more languages than that, but you have to write some custom code to allow Sling to use those alternative languages through the Use API. For example, I am right now about to try to figure out how to expose groovy or Kotlin through the Use API, so that I can do something like this:

```
<div data-sly-use.bean="myscript.groovy">${bean.valueFromGroovy}</div>
```

Comment: As a Sling/AEM developer with a career that pre-dates Sightly, I take umbrage with your comment that good Sling developers don't use JSPs any more. I suspect that Sightly appealed to people who were looking at JSPs full of java code - JSP 2.0 made this unnecessary and inadvisable, but that was the example provided by the devs that created Sling/CQ/AEM. I advise clients to use HTL, but only because it is conventional now - not because it is advantageous.

Comment: As a Sling/AEM developer with an AEM career that predates Sightly or even Adobe's ownership of the product, I'll point out that our own backgrounds are irrelevant to the merits of our statements. That being said, if you feel that my statement "good sling devs" don't use JSP anymore was too general, I'll happily grant you that. A modern view framework, be it sightly/htl or anything else, provide very real benefits over JSP - there is only _gain_ when leaving JSP behind. Separation of business logic, view assembly prior to response writing, many more that don't fit in this text limit...

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but HTL is still just compiling to servlets. I argue that well-written JSPs do this in a more convenient, maintainable way. Sightly's ideological goals ("allows HTML developers without Java knowledge to better participate in AEM projects") makes it awkward for devs that know what they're doing. For example, I'll use the JSTL c:set to assign long paths to easy to use variables; to do the same in HTL, you have to use a side effect in data-sly-test, making the code harder to read. HTL is far better than poorly written JSPs, but not quite as good as well written ones.

Comment: I'm not going to argue about it. I provided a wealth of information for avoiding JSP as OP requested. The OP also referenced Sun's denunciation of JSP, business logic separation being only 1 of many issues with JSP, and it seems you're only upset I've agreed with him/her about that. Sure, with discipline you can avoid that one single of many pitfalls in JSP, but if you're really upset about the industry's distaste for JSP, there are ostensibly millions of others to argue about that with besides myself.

Comment: This has gotten a bit silly, so we may have to agree to disagree. I advise clients to use HTL now, so I really don't think it is terrible. But I don't know of any denunciation of JSP by Sun - it's still on the Oracle site without caveat. Sun did recommend scriptlets not be used in 2003, if not earlier. This was the OP's complaint with the Sling examples, and I agree with him; JSPs with embedded Java code are horrible. Not doing it that way fixes the problem and has been simple since JSP2.0. If you want the last word, I'll let you have it now. ;)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the way with Apache Sling and derived products like Adobe CQ (or whatever it is called by now). I agree that this makes for badly written JSPs and hard to maintain software.

Using JSTL, as outlined by Robert Munteanu is the first step to creating cleaner code.

In my current job I wrote a framework that uses Servlet filters to inject Java classes as "controllers" into JSPs, based on their resource type. Accessing data or functionality in them is trivial and makes for clean(er) JSPs.

And then there's Cognifide's [Slice framework](https://github.com/Cognifide/Slice) which looks like it's solving a lot of these problems, but I've never gotten around to use it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're new to OSGi in general, so you need to know how to create services. If you can do that, you can create services that implement javax.servlet.Servlet --

This [LINK](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/servlets.html) is a good overview of how you'll shape your servlet components.

As Bertrand mentioned, Sling gives you a lot of freedom, so you'll need to play with Sling to understand how to design your apps using its methodology of resources and resource handlers (on top of OSGi services).